# "declared and not used" Error

Tags: go

I get this error saying that I'm not using a variable… but to my noob eyes, it looks like I am:

```
func Sqrt(x float64) float64 {

    z := float64(x);

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        z := z - (z*z - x) / (2 * z);
    }

    return z;
}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm missing about the language? I think it has to do with `=` vs. `:=` and scoping, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `:=` in your for-loop declares a new variable `z` which shadows the outer `z`. Turn it into a plain `=` to fix the problem.

```
func Sqrt(x float64) float64 {

    z := x

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        z = z - (z*z - x) / (2 * z);
    }

    return z;
}
```

By the way, for equal precision and a bit more speed you could try the following implementation which does two of your steps at once:

```
func Sqrt(x float64) float64 {
    z := x
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        a := z + x/z
        z = a/4 + x/a
    }
    return z
 }
```

Comment: what is the difference between `=` and `:=` in general?

Comment: `=` assigns a value to an existing variable, while `:=` declares a new variable and assigns a value to it. If you know C (or friends) it's sort of like `foo = 42` vs `int foo = 42`

Comment: @dubeegee a = b means "Let a have the value of b". a := b means "Declare a variable a that has the type and value of b".

Comment: @dubeegee: `=` [Variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations). `:=` [Short variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to look at the function

```
func Sqrt(x float64) (z float64) {
    z = x
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        z = z - (z*z - x)/(2*z);
    }
    return
}
```